# Adding rows to DataGrid in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I'm developing a small application which requires adding user-defined values to a grid. Problem is that even thought they add fine (I've checked in the debugger) they do not appear properly in the grid.

Screenshot:

[image: SCREEN SHOT].

**Here is the code:**

*XAML:*

```xml
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="defaultValueDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="150" Margin="0,0,10,0">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="valColumn" Binding="{Binding DefVal, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="SomeHeader" Width="*" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

*Definition of ItemSource collection and container class:*

```
public ObservableCollection<DefaultValue> defaultValues;

//Class:
public class DefaultValue
{
    public string DefVal;

    public DefaultValue(string val)
    {
        this.DefVal = val;
    }
}
```

*Initialization in the page constructor:*

```
    this.defaultValues = new ObservableCollection<DefaultValue>();
    this.defaultValueDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.defaultValues;
```

*And lastly function which adds values:*

```
private void AddNewDefaultValueBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.newDefaultValueTxtBx.Text))
    {
        this.defaultValues.Add(new DefaultValue(this.newDefaultValueTxtBx.Text));
        this.defaultValueDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.defaultValues;
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy, right? Right, but it does not work and I will appreciate tips and help.
Ps. I have used [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/03/21/using-the-silverlight-datagrid.aspx) tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

`public string DefVal;`

to

`public string DefVal {get;set;}`

Binding don't work on member variables it works on properties

and you don't need to reset the items source inside button click event

`this.defaultValueDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.defaultValues;`

Changes in observable collection will directly change the DataGrid

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. Reseting is some leftover from trying different approach. Cheers mate